# How do you unsubscribe from a ubiquity command

Tags: ubiquity

I can't seem to find details on how to unsubscribe from ubiquity commands.   The command list page only seems to have information about the installed commands and there are no links to deleting them.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to about:ubiquity in Firefox. Under the section "subscribed feeds" there should be an option to unsubscribe to command feeds you no longer desire.

Also, if you clear your entire browser history, it will delete all command feeds (this will be fixed by 0.2)

Answer (score 2):

The way to delete commands is to find them in the Subscribed Feeds section of the main help page:

1. ubiq help  |  about:ubiquity
2. Scroll down to "Subscribed Feeds" in the right hand column
3. Click '[unsubscribe]' for the one you want to delete.
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla/topics/how_do_you_edit_delete_the_default_ubiquity_commands_verbs

Also, you can find a utility to reset your ubiquity to default in \extensions\ubiquity@labs.mozilla.com\chrome\content\reset.html
EDIT1: The above file does nothing, please ignore.

EDIT2 (answer?): You can use the ffx addon SQLite Manager to open the \ubiquity_ann.sqlite database and remove all rows for the command you want to delete (there will be several rows, but they are identified by the url the script came from and so easy to identify).  When you restart firefox, the command will be gone.
(The code that populates the Commands page uses javascript to create an instance of UbiquitySetup object, and executes the method .createServices().commandSource which reads that SQLite database directly for a list of commands (returning an object or array of objects/commands to iterate through).  This seems to delete the command itself, since it will no longer be found in ubiquity or the command list.)

Good luck.